# How can i use md-radio-group with ng-repeat inside md-table?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm creating a Google-Form like application using angularJS and md-table, and to create my questionnaires i iterate through an array of questions, then through the possible answers:

```
<table md-table flex>
  <thead md-head>
    <tr md-row>
      <th md-column style="width: 99%;"></th>
      <th md-column ng-repeat="option in question.options" style="white-space: nowrap">
        {{option.name}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody md-body>
    <tr md-row ng-repeat="sub_item in question.sub_items">
      <td style="width: 99%;">{{sub_item.name}}</td>
      <md-radio-group ng-model="sub_item.answer" layout="row">
        <td ng-repeat="answer in question.options">
          <md-radio-button ng-value="{{answer.limit}}"></md-radio-button>
        </td>
      </md-radio-group>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But i cannot iterate through the answers, and i get something like this:
[image]

And get the error

> Blockquote angular.js:12808 Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'mdRadioGroup', required by directive 'mdRadioButton', can't be found!

I think when i use the `<td ng-repeat="answer in question.options">` i'm creating a new scope, and the `md-radio-group` directive can't recognize those `md-radio-button`'s. How can i make it works? I tried to iterate directly the `md-radio-button`'s, without td, but obviously doesn't work inside the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="sub_item in question.sub_items">
  <td style="width: 99%;">{{sub_item.name}}</td>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="sub_item.answer" layout="row">
    <td ng-repeat="answer in question.options">
      <md-radio-button ng-value="{{answer.limit}}"></md-radio-button>
    </td>
  </md-radio-group>
</tr>
```

with

```
<tr md-row ng-repeat="sub_item in question.sub_items">
      <td style="width: 99%;">{{sub_item.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="answer in question.options">
        <md-radio-group ng-model="sub_item.answer" layout="row">
          <md-radio-button ng-value="{{answer.limit}}"></md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

...it worked.